# How to append a link to a table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an ajax function that calls a method that returns a JSON file. I want to pull the information from the JSON and append it to the table. Which I can do like this:

```
function updateHome() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetHomePage", "Home")',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            response = $.parseJSON(result)

            $(function () {
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    var table = document.getElementById("deviceTable");

                    var $tr = $('<tr class="accordion" id="'+item.mac+'">').append(
                        $('<td>').text(item.name),
                        $('<td>').text(item.loc),
                        $('<td>').text(item.com),
                        $('<td>').text(item.status)
                    ).appendTo(table)
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This works as intended. However, I want to make one of the `td` a link using `<a href=` but I'm not sure how I can achieve this using `.text()`. How can I add different HTML elements to this table? 
Thanks!

Comment: "'m not sure how I can achieve this using .text()" — You can't. You use `append()`. Just like everywhere else in your code.

Comment: $('<td>').text(item.name) => $('<td>').html('<a href="#">' + item.name + '</a>'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text` sets the text content of your selection. It protects you from unintentionally injecting HTML.

`.html` sets the html content of your selection. Use that for a HTML string, or alternatively, use `.append`:

```
$('<td/>').append(
   $('<a/>', { href: '#', text: 'Anchor text' })
)
```